# How to wait then perform an action based on HTTPrequest response iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http

I have class that post a tweet to twitter using HTTP Post

here is a bit of code
`PostTweet.h`

```
@interface PostTweet : NSObject
- (void)postMyTweet;
@end
```

`PostTweet.m`

```
- (void)postMyTweet 
{

    accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             allAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([allAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 userAccount = [allAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                 userName = userAccount.username;
                 NSURL * reqURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ENDPOINT_MEDIA_UPLOAD];
                 NSDictionary * parameter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetTitle forKey:@"status"];

                 SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                              URL:reqURL
                                                                       parameters:parameter];
                 [twitterInfoRequest addMultipartData:tweetImage withName:PARAM_MEDIA type:CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA filename:nil];

                 [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:userAccount];

                 [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      //show status after done
                      long result = [urlResponse statusCode];



                      //Let us say that every thing is ok and I got 200 response 
                      if (result == 200)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"%ld",result);
                      }




                  }
                  ];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Not authorized");
         }
     }];

}
```

In my `viewcontroller.m`

```
- (void) actuallySendTweet
{
    PostTweet * pt = [[PostTweet alloc] init];

    [pt postTweet];
    NSLog(@"Done");
}
```

The Question is: after calling The testMethod, How to wait for the http request response and I can do anything based on the response.

What happens now is that as soon as I call the testMethod the `NSLog` perform right away and does not wait for the http response.

Comment: You really don't want your main queue to wait for the network response. You should be doing whatever post-tweet action your want in your completion block (where you have that `NSLog(@"%ld", result);`). Effectively, in asynchronous programming, you should be separating the initiation of the request from the handling of the response from the server. If absolutely necessary, you can present some UI that tells the user that background stuff is happening (e.g. a view with a `UIActivityViewIndicator`), initiate the request, and have the completion block of `performRequestWithHandler` remove it.

Comment: The technical answer is "do it in `performRequestWithHandler`", but if you're looking for less abstract answer, you have to give us a less abstract question. Namely, what precisely do you want to do after posting this tweet? It might be easier for us to make constructive suggestions if you tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just want to show a completion message based on the http request result. For example if the result is 200, MBProgressHUD with success message will pop up(I know how to do this part). Other then 200, a failed messaged will pop up. @Rob

Comment: Then you should just put that inside the `completion` block for `performRequestWithHandler`, not after your invocation of `postTweet`. Easy as can be. And don't use that barrier call of the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As here you are using completion block. The thread does not wait for the execution of block.
So it you want that execution of block should complete and precess the data before finishing the execution of method, you can use,

```
dispatch_group_t
```

I am editing your method for that,

```
- (void)postMyTweet 
{

    accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             allAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([allAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 userAccount = [allAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                 userName = userAccount.username;
                 NSURL * reqURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ENDPOINT_MEDIA_UPLOAD];
                 NSDictionary * parameter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetTitle forKey:@"status"];

                 SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                              URL:reqURL
                                                                       parameters:parameter];
                 [twitterInfoRequest addMultipartData:tweetImage withName:PARAM_MEDIA type:CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA filename:nil];

                 [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:userAccount];

                 [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      //show status after done
                      long result = [urlResponse statusCode];



                      //Let us say that every thing is ok and I got 200 response 
                      if (result == 200)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"%ld",result);
                      }


                      dispatch_group_leave(group);
                  }
                  ];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Not authorized");
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }
     }];

     dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(group);

}
```

Now from this you can get idea.

Comment: Obviously, don't do `dispatch_group_wait` on the main queue.

Comment: How can I pass back the HTTP response result to the viewcontroller ..?? @Harsh

Comment: there are some methods but (as apple says) I would recommend you to write your own delegate.

Comment: @Rob can you please suggest the alternative or what improvement requires here? It will help me out as well.

Comment: @Harsh You never should have anything blocking (such as `dispatch_group_wait`) on the main queue. If you need to have something performed when the tweet is done, then just put that in the `performRequestWithHandler` completion block. And if you want the UI to be locked while you wait for the tweet (which is a bad UX, but that's up to iMubarak), you present view with `UIActivityIndicatorView` before tweeting and take it down in the `performRequestWithHandler` completion block. If you give me example of precisely what you want to do, I can give you examples of how to do it.

Comment: @Rob I used the same (dispatch_group_wait) while getting image using "ALAssetsLibrary" in method "getImage" returns image, and called method [self getImage:imagePath];. Now I get control back from the getImage before blocks get execute. In this scenario am I doing it rightly or not?

Comment: @Harsh Using `group` this way is a non-standard and it makes me queazy to enter the group on one thread and leave it from another. Typically you use semaphores to coordinate threads, namely `dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);` before starting the async process, do `dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);` near end of async block and then `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` from calling queue. Not sure if that's the problem, but it's how you typically do it. **But never do this `wait` from the main queue.** These methods are async for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you wanted to coordinate two different threads `dispatch_semaphore_t` might be more appropriate than `dispatch_group_t`.

Second, and more importantly, you should not take an asynchronous method such as `performRequestWithHandler`, invoke it from the main queue in a synchronous manner. You *never* should be blocking the main queue.

Fortunately `performRequestWithHandler` gives us a `handler` block which we can use to perform actions after the tweet is done. In your comments, you say you simply want to update your HUD after the tweet, so you should do that `performRequestWithHandler` (dispatching that UI update back to the main queue, because, as [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SLRequest/performRequestWithHandler%3a) says, "handler is not guaranteed to be called on any particular thread"):

```
- (void)postMyTweet
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType  *accountType  = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *allAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([allAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount    *userAccount = [allAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSURL        *reqURL      = [NSURL URLWithString:ENDPOINT_MEDIA_UPLOAD];
                 NSDictionary *parameter   = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetTitle forKey:@"status"];

                 SLRequest *twitterRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                          URL:reqURL
                                                                   parameters:parameter];

                 [twitterRequest addMultipartData:tweetImage withName:PARAM_MEDIA type:CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA filename:nil];
                 [twitterRequest setAccount:userAccount];
                 [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      if (error)
                          NSLog(@"tweet fail; error = %@", error);
                      else
                      {
                          long result = [urlResponse statusCode];

                          if (result == 200)
                              NSLog(@"%ld",result);
                          else
                              NSLog(@"Unexpected response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]);
                      }

                      // Dispatch UI updates back to main queue

                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          // do your MBProgressHUD stuff here
                      });
                  }];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Not authorized");
         }
     }];
}
```

You also asked "How can I pass the HTTP response result to the viewcontroller?" You obviously do all of this in `performRequestWithHandler`, where you have the HTTP response (and the response data).

---

If you want `postTweet` to operate synchronously, then best practices would dictate that you don't submit it from the main queue (because, at the risk of sounding like a broken record, you never want to block the main queue). But you could have `actuallySendTweet` dispatch this tweet from a background queue, e.g.:

```
- (void) actuallySendTweet
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        PostTweet * pt = [[PostTweet alloc] init];

        [pt postTweetSynchronously];

        NSLog(@"Done");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Now do any UI updates you want here.

            // For example, do your MBProgressHUD update here.
        });
    });
}

- (void)postTweetSynchronously
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType  *accountType  = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *allAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([allAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount    *userAccount = [allAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSURL        *reqURL      = [NSURL URLWithString:ENDPOINT_MEDIA_UPLOAD];
                 NSDictionary *parameter   = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetTitle forKey:@"status"];

                 SLRequest *twitterRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                          URL:reqURL
                                                                   parameters:parameter];

                 [twitterRequest addMultipartData:tweetImage withName:PARAM_MEDIA type:CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA filename:nil];
                 [twitterRequest setAccount:userAccount];

                 [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      // do whatever you want here, perhaps updating some class properties

                      // now that we're done, signal the semaphore
                      dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                  }];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Not authorized");
             dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); // make sure to signal here, too
         }
     }];

     dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Comment: If you refer back to my main Question, you will notice that I am calling (postMyTweet) from viewcontroller.m class. The method which handle posting tweet to twitter is actually in another class. So when I call it, it is doing the job but the NSLog@"Done"; doesn't wait for postMyTweet method to finish and return the http response result. This is my question: how to make it wait and return the response result then I can do any action. Thanks @Rob

Comment: @iMubarak The answer to "how to make it wait" is "you can do it using semaphores, but its inadvisable to do that from the main queue." But I've revised answer to show how you could post your tweet synchronously, but I also demonstrate how to make sure you don't do that on the main queue if you want to be careful about it.